# php framework for json-api-centric project

Tags: php, json, frameworks

I need to start a project that will be json-API-centric, which means that most of the project will be an API based on exchanges of json structures.

I want to find a framework that will jumpstart my project with :

- auto-documentation (documentation of public APIs are extracted from the code for public clients, private APIs are extracted for trusted clients)
- API keys
- metrics of usage
- ..

Do you know if such an API-centric framework already exists in PHP ?

Comment: I would look at frameworks that mimic Ruby on Rails in PHP, such as Symphony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question long ago.
This is the closest framework i have found so far meeting my requirements: http://phpsx.org/

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework has a built in class for dealing with JSON

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a good solution myself and figured I would share the ZoHo https://www.zoho.com/general/blog/announcing-the-zoho-projects-api.html